how can I install a 60" bathroom vanity if my space between the two walls is 59.5"?
My vanity was custom made about 30 years ago and the space wall to wall is about 59.5 inches.  Is there any way to install a standard 60" cabinet.  I do plan on custom ordering the vanity top since it is also a single sink on the right side rather than the center

You need to make the cabinet smaller or the wall wider.  The wall probably has 1/2 drywall on it, so with careful measurements, it might be done.

A picture of the cabinet sides/ends will be of value to determine if there is any give in the way the cabinet is made, otherwise you would be best to remove the drywall on both walls to get it in, and reapply and finish the drywall so the cabinet is centered in the wall space,

If the walls are nonstructural, perhaps you could replace 2x4 studs with 2x3 and gain the space you need that way.

Get a cabinet designed to be trimmed to fit the space, making sure that the actual body is narrow enough to fit; kitchen cabinets, which often abut a wall, are available with an extra-wide face so the can be "scribed" to an exact fit.
Or move the wall. Removing the wallboard and then fixing it up to fit might give you enough space, but that assumes no error in measurements trips you up.
